# No module named 'django.templates' Django

Tags: python, django

Не могу отрендерить страницу вот такая ошибка:

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'django.templates'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.templates'
Exception Location: /Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 126
Python Executable:  /Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/sites/dom_u_morya',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/sites/dom_u_morya',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python3.5',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/Vadim/Documents/Python/testEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Вс, 5 Июн 2016 16:52:54 +0000
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def houses_list(request):
    return render(request, "houses/houses_list.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from houses.views import houses_list



  urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', houses_list, name='home')
]
```

Структура темплйтс:

```
templates
        houses
              houses_list.html
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.templates.context_processors.debug',
                'django.templates.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из текста исключения, модуля django.templates не существует. Существует django.template. Вам нужно везде заменить templates на template.

Comment: есть не большая проблема, если я меняю название папки на template у меня action в views.py  не видет темплейта и возникает соответствующая ошибка. Я как новичок Джанге,  обьясните где везде изменить  с  django.templates на django.template в каких файлах искать? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @ВадимВова, нужно изменить строки с названием модуля - django.templates поменять на django.template. Без переименования каталога. Также полный путь к каталогу с шаблонами нужно добавить в массив 'DIRS'. Пример - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#the-dirs-option

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ошибка, при изменении папки templates локальной для приложения pycharm также изменил настройка в settings.py помечено **

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.**template**.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.**template**.context_processors.debug',
            'django.**template**.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```